# registerEntityTypeCtor initializers does not seem to trigger when using property path expand

Tags: javascript, breeze

I want all Date types in my entities to always be converted to momentjs. The solution (Code 2) I used for this works fine for getResources (Code 1), the initializer is triggered for both the 'Event and 'Shift' entities. But when I call getUser the expand works as it should and I get the right data for both 'Order' and 'Event', but the initializer for 'Event' never triggers. Any ideas why? Is it because I'm using a property path expand?

Also, if you can think of a better solution to convert all Date types in my entities to momentjs I will gladly accept that too.

Code 1:

```
var getResources = function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Resources")
        .expand("Event, Shift")
        .orderBy("ResourceId");

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .fail(fail);
    }

var getUser = function () {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("LoggedInUser")
        .expand("Order.Event")
        .orderBy("Email");

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
         .fail(fail);
}
```

Code 2:

```
function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Shift', null, momentInitializer);
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Event', null, momentInitializer);
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Order', null, momentInitializer);            
}

function momentInitializer(entity) {
    var newMoment,
        prop;

    for (prop in entity) {
        if (ko.isObservable(entity[prop])) {
            if (entity[prop]() instanceof Date) {
                newMoment = ko.observable(moment(entity[prop]()));
                entity[prop] = newMoment;
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better and more detailed answer for this, but from what I understand you are probably trying to display the date in a given format, not actually convert it in the database, correct?

If you are using a binding handler such as Knockout.js you can just change the format in which it is displayed instead of converting the date/time stamp.  I am always cautious of converting the dates just to display them because I have had issue in the past with the database getting mad at me for such a thing.

Here is an example of a custom binding handler to show date time as May 29th, 2013, 2:22:00 pm

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DateTime = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var date = moment(value());
        var strDate = date.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
        $(element).text(strDate);
    }
};
```

Comment: What I'm making is a kind of calendar/booking-system, so I will be working a lot with dates, and I want to put as much of that work on the client side as possible. I was thinking that, if the client converted all dates to momentjs at fetch time it would be easier to work with and then at save time I would just convert it back to proper database format.